# How do I tell the type of websocket onmessage's parameter?

Tags: javascript, websocket, blob, arraybuffer

Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/MessageEvent it states attribute data is of type DOMString| Blob | ArrayBuffer. How do I tell it which type I want? Or how do I know which type I get?

Answer (score 52):

The appropriate two types of frames that a server can send are text frames and binary frames ([5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)). The [`ws.binaryType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/WebSocket#Attributes) allows you to define in which format you'd like to obtain the binary data.

- Binary data: depending on `binaryType` being set to either `arraybuffer` or `blob`
- Text data: string

To determine the type, you can use:

- `e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer`
- `e.data instanceof Blob`
- `typeof e.data === "string"`

[Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#feedback-from-the-protocol):

> 4. If *type* indicates that the data is Text, then initialize *event*'s `data` attribute to *data*.
>
> If *type* indicates that the data is Binary, and `binaryType` is set to "`blob`", then initialize *event*'s `data` attribute to a new `Blob` object that represents *data* as its raw data.
>
> If type indicates that the data is Binary, and `binaryType` is set to "`arraybuffer`", then initialize *event*'s `data` attribute to a new read-only `ArrayBuffer` object whose contents are `data`.

Answer (score 2):

> "How do I tell it which type I want?"

The type of the data in a websocket frame is determined by the sender (see [1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)) and hence cannot be set by the receiver. If textual data is sent, then the type of `e.data` is `string`. If binary data is sent, then `e.data` will be an instance of either `ArrayBuffer`, or `Blob`, depending on the value of the `ws.binaryType` property set by the receiver.

> "Or how do I know which type I get?"

This has already been answered by pimvdb.